# How could i make the MediaView has the same height and width of the layout boundaries when the program is running?

Tags: javafx

i want to know how the mediaview could get full screen and when the stage is resized the mediaview  do it as well. i did this but it doesn't do what i want.

```
public class Controller implements Initializable 
{

    @FXML
    private MediaView mediaView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        Media media = new Media("file:///D:/Sound.MP4");
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mediaPlayer);

        mediaPlayer.play();

        mediaPlayer.setOnReady(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Add Pane to scene
                DoubleProperty width = mediaView.fitWidthProperty();
                DoubleProperty height = mediaView.fitHeightProperty();

                width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mediaView.sceneProperty(),"width"));
                height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(mediaView.sceneProperty(),"height"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: don't repost a question, instead edit the first with details as needed to make it answerable, namely a [mcve] as has been suggested :)

Comment: i just want to know how to solve my problem, this is all what i want

Answer (score 0):

the answer of this question is the next line

mediaView.setPreserveRatio(false);

because the video doesn't keep its proportion therefore you could adjust the mediaview to the boundaries